# Where is Themes.dll?

Tags: orchardcms

I have been looking at the new Bootstrap theme from Wiggleware, which goes well beyond any other Orchard Theme I have seen. There is quite a bit of code associated with this theme but I have not been able to figure out how this is compiled. There is no Themes\bin directory and no Themes.dll that I can find anywhere. So where does the code end up?

I ask because I need to do something similar but whenever I try to set up a theme the same way it only works under the debugger and won't deploy correctly (namespace name missing).

Comment: Bootstrap theme is a project in itself, set up the theme using the command: codegen theme MyNewTheme CreateProject:true

Comment: I actually set up the project manually, but I set it up under Themes/Themes/MyNewTheme instead of creating a new project Themes/MyNewTheme.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid question that arises only because I didn't understand how Orchard Themes are laid out in VS. For the sake of anyone else making this mistake, please note that there are two types of Orchard theme:

'Ordinary' themes live under the 'Themes' Theme and so appear in the Solution Explorer under Themes/Themes. These themes do not have their own project and just share the 'Themes' project.

'Project' themes have their own project and in the Solution Explorer they appear as Themes/MyNewTheme. These themes compile just like a module.

Hope that helps